# How do i write(print) to the document from request block in node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, cheerio

I wrote some server side code that should get live data from yahoo and then print it to the console and to the browser when i'm running the server, the problem is that i can't find a function that is printing to the document from the request block.
This is my code:

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var util = require('util');

tempvar = null;
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    //writing the headers of our response
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });

    // Variable Deceleration 
    // TODO: move from the global scope
    var ticker = "IBM";
    var yUrl = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=" + ticker;
    var keyStr = new Array();
    testTemp = null;

    //
    // The main call to fetch the data, parse it and work on it.    
    //
    request(yUrl, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);


            // the keys - We get them from a certain class attribute
            var span = $('.time_rtq_ticker>span');
            stockValue = $(span).text();
            console.log("Stock  - " + ticker + " --> text " + stockValue);
            //res.write("Stock  - " + ticker + " --> text " + stockValue);
            testTemp = stockValue;
// 

-- end of request --
        res.write("Stock value for: " + ticker + " is --> " + testTemp + "\n");
        res.write("12333\n");
        res.write('something\n');

        //printing out back to the client the last line
        res.end('end of demo');

## Heading ##
        }

    }); 

});

server.listen(1400, '127.0.0.1');
```

This is the error that i got in the console
Files\node.js\node_modules\YfTemp.js:49 >>;
 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at Module._compile 
 at Object.Module._extensions..js  at Module.load  at Function.Modul._load  at Function.Module.runMain  at strartup  at node.js:906:3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Request` works **asynchronously**. You need to put the printing part of your script *inside* the request callback block. Otherwise, `ticker` is not defined yet when the printing lines are reached.

```
request(yUrl, function(error, response, body) {
     if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);


        // the keys - We get them from a certain class attribute
        var span = $('.time_rtq_ticker>span');
        stockValue = $(span).text();
        console.log("Stock  - " + ticker + " --> text " + stockValue);
        //res.write("Stock  - " + ticker + " --> text " + stockValue);
        testTemp = stockValue;

        // -- end of request --
        res.write("Stock value for: " + ticker + " is --> " + testTemp + "\n");
        res.write("12333\n");
        res.write('something\n');

        //printing out back to the client the last line
        res.end('end of demo');

     }


});
```

Comment: Ok, i've made the changes that you suggested and i'm getting this error in the console:
c:\Program Files\node.js\node_modules\YfTemp.js:49
>>;
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Module._compile <module.js:439:25>
    at Object.Module._extensions..js <module.js:474:10>
    at Module.load <module.js:356:32>
    at Function.Modul._load <module.js:312:12>
    at Function.Module.runMain <module.js:497:10>
    at strartup <node.js:119:16>
    at node.js:906:3

Comment: Ok. Could you edit your post and include the exact changes you made, the error code, and also what's on lines 119 & 906 of your `node.js` file ?

Comment: I've editied the entire post, could you pls check it ? 
I just want to print from the request function some sata that i took from Yahoo finance, the stockValue variable that holds the some text from the HTML file.

Comment: So i editied my entire post as you asked, can you have a look?

Comment: You have a `Syntax Error`, it should very easy for you to debug. At least, far easier for you than for me. I can't comment lines to see when it stops working, I can't see the lines number...I mean, did you try that at least ? I think it will take you far less time to debug a syntax error than to wait for somebody to do it for you on SO...

But what's the `## Heading ##` bit you added to your code ? I don't understand it